# Robot-Sikuli script throwing exception error when run from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, sikuli

I am trying to run robot script with sikuli library and related code from jenkins. When run from terminal it works fine. But when run through jenkins it throws a exception as

> com.github.rainmanwy.robotframework.sikulilib.exceptions.TimeoutException:
>   Timeout happend, could not find P(windows_start.PNG) S: 0.7

```
Java version: java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Code as :

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SikuliLibrary    mode=NEW


*** Test Cases ***
SC_1
        Start Sikuli Process
    Add Image Path  C:\\SikuliImage
    Click   windows_start.PNG
```

Comment: The message says it can't find the start button. Have you compared a screenshot of the desktop with the one of your develoment machine and validate that the image is correct for the server?

Comment: My development machine and server both are same.When run from terminal it works fine but when run from Jenkins which is also on same machine it throws this exeption

Comment: Is Jenkins started manually, or running under a service account?

Comment: Jenkins is running as a service

Comment: Try starting Jenkins manually and see if there is a difference when you run your test.

Comment: Started jenkins manually, but still facing the same exception.

Comment: Yes starting jenkins manually solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that Jenkins don't have access to Image path i.e  C:\SikuliImage.
Try to add path which is same as the Jenkins path i.e in case of *unix, we have /var/lib/jenkins, so that Jenkins have access to it.

Comment: Tried changing the path to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins, but still facing the same exception.